# How do I check the wear level of a SSD

Tags: ssd

How do I check the wear level of an SSD? Are there general diagnostics tools or is it specific to the SSD?

The SSD in question is the Samsung 840 EVO.

Comment: Indeed.  There exists tools like [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1926483/ssd-diagnostic-tools.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `smartctl` command, or the respective smart tools available on your platform?

As noted here [Can an SSD notify the hosting OS that its wear level is getting high?](https://serverfault.com/questions/142188/can-an-ssd-notify-the-hosting-os-that-its-wear-level-is-getting-high#142204)

> Intel SSDs (and others) offer wear information via SMART

`smartctl -a /dev/ssd`

> results in something like:
>
> ```
> ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH 
> ...cut...
> 232 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail
> 233 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age
> ```

Comment: And what about windows?